# Change color of matInput on Mattool bar

Tags: angular, angular-material

The Mat Tool bar overriding the text box color. how can i change textbox color to white and border should be black?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx3uny?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the following code in the scss/css file that you are using for that component

```
  .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-text-field__input {
     color: rgba(232, 227, 227, 0.87);
   }
```

If that does not work, then put it in your index.html which will be enclosed in

```
<style>
   .mdc-text-field:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-text-field__input {
      color: rgba(232, 227, 227, 0.87);
   } 
</style
```

You asked how to change the border color but from what I am seeing in your stackblitz link, it is already showing black. I will drop a screenshot here. [image]

Comment: How can we make entire text box color like exact  like basic Material  Input https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: I tried to add search box but it's little bit ugly can we adjust actual text box in the middle of the tool bar? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zx3uny?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.css,app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html

Comment: trying setting the mat-form-field appearance to "fill"